# Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT while removing USB

Tags: android

We have modified AOSP so that we can browse USB device (connected to PC) in the emulator.

The problem is if I eject the USB without unmounting I get 'Unfortunately the process android.process.media has stopped" dialog.

In the logcat I see the following:

```
D/DirectVolume(   98): Volume usb1 /mnt/USB/USBDISK1 partition 8:49 removed
D/Vold    (   98): Volume usb1 state changing 4 (Mounted) -> 5 (Unmounting)
D/MountService(  276): volume state changed for /mnt/USB/USBDISK1 (mounted -> unmounted)
I/StorageNotification(  430): Media {/mnt/USB/USBDISK1} state changed from {mounted} -> {unmounted}
D/VoldCmdListener(   98): volume shared /mnt/sdcard ums
E/MountService(  276): Failed to read response to volume shared /mnt/sdcard ums
D/MountService(  276): volume state changed for /mnt/USB/USBDISK1 (unmounted -> bad_removal)
I/StorageNotification(  430): Media {/mnt/USB/USBDISK1} state changed from {unmounted} -> {bad_removal}
D/MountService(  276): sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL dat=file:///mnt/USB/USBDISK1 (has extras) }
D/MountService(  276): sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT dat=file:///mnt/USB/USBDISK1 (has extras) }
D/AndroidRuntime(  827): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  827): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6271288)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  827): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT dat=file:///mnt/USB/USBDISK1 flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider$1@a6a85f38
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:765)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider$1.onReceive(MediaProvider.java:238)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:755)
E/AndroidRuntime(  827):    ... 9 more
I/TvNotificationBuilder(  655): topAppWindowChanged
I/USB BreakIn Service(  530): USB Service, Action Intent Received : android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED
D/dalvikvm(  530): GC_CONCURRENT freed 479K, 18% free 7262K/8771K, paused 16ms+0ms, total 34ms
I/USB BreakIn Service(  530): USB BREAKOUT, Detached USB Device Name - JetFlash-MassStorageDevice-PQHJ742X and Mount Path - /mnt/USB/USBDISK1
I/USBBroadcastReceiver( 1140): ### onReceive called usbbreakin.ACTION_USB_BREAKOUT
I/USBBroadcastReceiver( 1140): ###getContext org.droidtv.contentexplorer.MainActivity@a6aba858
I/USBDeviceHandler( 1140): ###PROCESS_USB_DETACHED 
I/TvSettingsManager( 1473): Constructing TvSettingsManager...
```

Any hints?

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: There is an NPE (MediaProvider.java:238). Have you made any modifications there? Post the source code for MediaProvider.java

Comment: No modification are done for the file MediaProvider.java

Comment: OK, just checked MediaProvider.java's code. It looks like the `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT` does not contain the required extra and so code in lines 234~235 is returning null: `StorageVolume storage = (StorageVolume)intent.getParcelableExtra(
                        StorageVolume.EXTRA_STORAGE_VOLUME);`. Hence the NPE in line 238: `if (storage.getPath().equals(mExternalStoragePaths[0])) {`.

Comment: Just before the exception I see: <pre><code> D/MountService(  276): sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT dat=file:///mnt/USB/USBDISK1 (has extras) } <pre><code> .... does this not indicate the intent has extras so not NULL?